# Preact Particles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact, particles.js

I'm creating a Preact component for using [tsParticles](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles) library but nothing appears.

I'm porting the [React project](https://github.com/matteobruni/react-tsparticles) but something isn't compatible probably.

You can checkout the component here: https://github.com/matteobruni/preact-particles

This is how I'm using it:

```
<Particles id="tsparticles" params={{
    background: {
        color: "#000000",
    },
    particles: {
        number: { value: 100 },
        move: { enable: true }
    }
}} />
```

Comment: So in react its working but not in preact ?

Comment: Exactly, I've updated the question with all links

Comment: I think when extending getting an prototype issue, did you raised as a issue in github for the package

Comment: They're all mine, I'm trying to fix that issue

Comment: Ohhh cool,  great 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the `componentShouldUpdate` method with a weak condition that didn't worked with Preact.